# Is there any way to open kaggle json file from google drive in colab?

Tags: json, google-colaboratory, kaggle

Normally I need to upload kaggle json file for using Kaggle dataset in google colab. And for this, we need to use this code.

```
!pip install kaggle
from google.colab import files 
files.upload()
```

But, I want to upload the json file from google drive. Is it possible? What should I do about this?

```
!pip install kaggle
from google.colab import files 
files.open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/json kaggle')
```

It gives me an error. and error msg is-

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d57806ba75a7> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install kaggle')
      2 from google.colab import files
----> 3 files.open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/json kaggle')
      4 #files.upload() #download and upload json file

AttributeError: module 'google.colab.files' has no attribute 'open'
```

Thank you.